# Mqtt.js how to handle multiple topics

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, iot, esp8266

I'm using multiple ESP8266 to monitor multiple rooms around my house. And I was wondering what is the best way to handle the incoming data if for each room I'm waiting for a specific temperature level to turn on the AC or Heater.

Do I handle all the data and the turning off and on the AC/Heater in a global `.on message method` or do I create for each room a `.on message`? I'm using MQTT.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt)

```
this.client.on("message", (topic, message) => {
  console.log(`Received ${message}`);
  const roomId = JSON.parse(message);
  this.onReceiveMessage(topic, message);
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will only ever be one event when a message is delivered to the client, if you add more than one on `message` event listener they will all be called with the same `topic` and `message` values for a given message.

So there is no value in registering more than 1 on `message` client, you should then filter on the supplied `topic`, how you then choose to organise the code is entirely up to you and what actions you wish to take.